# want to access and override this specific a:hover value

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="nav-font  nav-item-3">
    <a href="/arc/place" class="top_nav">favorite places</a>
</div>
```

and would like to target the link color for favorite places. I have the following jquery:

```
$('.nav-font').on('mouseover',function(){
  //console.log('here i am');
  $(this).addClass('light-color');
});
```

but it doesn't overrride the a:hover. How would I more specifically set the value here?

thx

update #1:

here's sample css (doing one or the other). I thought the first would be more 'specific' but the standard a:hover that I have is still taking precedence. Appreciate the help!

```
.light-class a:hover{
  color: #f5e9d1;
}

.light-class{
  color: #f5e9d1;
}
```

Comment: Simply adding a class won't change anything, the class needs to have defined styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would affect that the same way you intend to affect the link. by declaring it in the css:

```
.light-color a{
    color:#ff6600;
}

.light-color a:hover{
    color:#ff0066;
}
```

Obviously use your own colors and make the selectors appropriate, but that's the general idea.

If, however, this answer is just presumptuous, you could also post your css so we can see exactly what you are doing with .light-color

EDIT:

So if you have already tried this, perhaps being more specific with your selectors will give higher priority to the newly added class:

```
.nav-font.light-color a.top_nav, .nav-font.light-color a.top_nav:hover{
    color: #f5e9d1;
}
```

Comment: so this I had your second version but it wasn't taking precedence over the the standard a:hover color.  I could very well by doing some stupid other mistake. added an update above....

Comment: so I created a fiddle and this looks like it is correct. http://jsfiddle.net/w6hNf/ Thx Kai - I probably have something else going on.

Comment: then the next step is to inspect the element to see what selectors are applying the color. Remember, in css the more specific the selector the higher priority it gets. so you might need to drill it down. I updated to illustrate

Answer (score 0):

Your `.on` is on `.nav-font`, so it's adding the class there.  The `a:hover` is inside, and overrules its container.  If you do this instead:

```
$('.nav-font a').on('mouseover',function(){
  $(this).addClass('light-color');
});
```

Then it'll target the `a` instead, and `$(this)` will refer to the `a` and add the class there.  You can abbreviate this to:

```
$('.nav-font a').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('light-color');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you're saying you have a color already defined in your css for the hover. Perhaps something like:

```
.top_nav:hover {
    color: #990000;
}
```

and you would like to make sure that gets overridden when applying the new .light-color class. If those assumptions are correct, then what you want to do is make sure your selector to override the color has a higher [css specificity](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/understanding_c) than your normal hover. Something like this should do the trick:

```
.light-color .top_nav:hover {
    color: #000099;
}
```

If you require even more specificity you can continue to add to your selector until the style overrides your initial hover color:

```
div.nav-font.nav-item-3.light-color a.top_nav:hover {
    color: #000099;
}
```

Usually you will try to only be as specific as you absolutely need, so you don't end up hurting yourself later on if you need to override your style again. Make sure you check some docs on specificity.

Personally, I try to stick to these rules:

- avoid !important at all costs
- avoid id selectors whenever possible like #my_id, as they're very difficult to override
- specific selectors like div.my_class where simply .my_class will do. This helps with specificity overrides, but also makes things more flexible if you want to reuse your class on something that isn't a div.